# How to install magento 2.2.4 in server?

Tags: installation, magento2.2.4

I am trying to install Magento 2.2.4 in GoDaddy hosting.

Actually, I have a website on Magento-1.9. So, I have created Beta folder and **copied all Magento-2.2.4 files into Beta**.

When i tried to install Magento by domain.com/Beta, It redirecting to my domain.com.

But, If we create sample **index.php** file with welcome to new world text, Its opening.

Comment: How are you trying?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, Please check my updated question

Comment: Rename root `.htaccess` file cleared cache than check.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install Magento 2.2.4 with app installer of godady

In Godady you have to change .htaccess file for many locations like root, pub/static, etc for uploaded default magento source

Instead of uploading source, you can try using app installer given by them.

Comment: Please see once my question. Its just modified

Comment: have you updated url in db?

Comment: thank you Prashant Valanda. it is working fine by installer of godaddy

Comment: i have one dobut. presently i am using  two websites. one is magento 1.9.1.1 and second one is magento 2.2.4. but magento 1.9 requires php5.5 version but magento 2 requires php 7.1.  i want to run two sites in one hosting can you give any suggestion.